# How to translate software description in software-center

Tags: software-center, translation

I want to ask you how / where to translate software description shown in Ubuntu Software Center. Thank you.

Comment: In light of additional information, please review the answers and re-select your accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Package descriptions are translated in the ddtp-ubuntu pseudo-package, see

https://launchpad.net/ddtp-ubuntu

Comment: Nightmonkey is much more efficient for focused translation on important packages.

Answer (score 1):

The descriptions in Software Centre are called Package Descriptions and can be translated here: https://launchpad.net/ddtp-ubuntu

If you search certain packages, or easily want to filter stuff like 'only the short descriptions', you can use Nightmonkey: http://nightmonkey.ubuntu.hu/